# Palindroms & Monads

Tags: haskell

I'm new to the Haskell. I am finding following task difficult:

> Enter a string of characters. Output all palindromes to the file (use the IO monad to work with the file system and input / output, use the list monad to work with the strings).`

Any code is may be helpful. Thank you in advance!

This is what I have tried so far:

```
palindrome :: Char -> [String]
palindrome n
    | n < 0  = []
    | even n = map (\front -> front ++ reverse front) fronts
    | odd n  = map (\front -> front ++ tail (reverse front)) fronts
    where ispalindrome :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> Bool
    ispalindrome x = show x = reverse (show x)

main = do
    input <- getline
    putStrLn print :: IO ()
```

Comment: Tips: 1. the input of palindrome function is String not Char, so the type signature is palindrome::String->[String]. 2. String is not number, cannot compare to Num, you may be need length function. 3. you have defined the ispalindrome funcion, but has not  used in the your code.

Comment: Another hint: to test for equality in `ispalindrome` use `==` not `=`. Also you need to pay attention to indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**isPalindrome**

My haskell is a bit rusty so I don't promise the code below will work %100 yet I tried to stick to the main idea.I hope this answer helps. If you think anything is wrong both logically and syntactically, just write a comment and I will fix it asap.

```
isPalindrome :: [Char] -> Boolean
isPalindrome w = isPalindrome' w reverse w
    where
        isPalindrome' :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Boolean
        isPalindrome' [] []         = true
        isPalindrome' (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == y then isPalindrome' xs ys  else false
        isPalindrome' _ _           = false
```

function above should be fine for checking for palindromes.

for writing to file part, you can create a list of palindromes first, then write all palindromes to a file in another function. so basically, first you split your string into words, then for words in given string you find palindromes, then you write the palindromes into a file.

**how to read string from user?**

```
main = do 
        userInput <- getLine
```

**how to split word with delimiter?**

```
split :: Char -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
split delimiter string = split' delimiter string [] []
    where
        split' :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
        split' delim [] substr splittedStr     = splittedStr if substr == [] else reverse substr ++ splittedStr
        split' delim (x:xs) substr splittedStr = if x == delim then split' delim xs [] (reverse substr) ++ splittedSubstr else split' delim xs (x ++ substr) splittedSubstr
```

main idea is you stack characters until you see your delimeter and store them in a list when you see a delimiter.

**how to filter palindromes in list?**

to filter palindromes in list you use haskell's filter function as

```
filter isPalindrome (split ' ' userInput)
```

In the end, you can write a main block to run all of this in right order

```
main = do
        userInput <- getLine
        let splittedInput = split ' ' userInput
        let palindromes   = filter isPalindrome splittedInput
        let output        = concat (intersperse "\n" palindromes)
        writeFile "file.txt" output
```

Comment: there some issue about in line 3: .hs:3:1: error: parse error on input ‘where’
  |
3 | where   | ^^^^^

Comment: ok, this issue above fixed by indetation, but here something with 'if'-function:        6:59: error: parse error on input ‘if’
  |
6 |         isPalindrome' (x:xs) (y:ys) = isPalindrome' xs ys if x == y else false   |

Comment: you should change the if-then-else sugar syntax as above

Comment: and the same put 'then' in this line?: split' delim [] substr splittedStr     = splittedStr if substr == [] else reverse substr ++ splittedStr   -- coz the same parse error with 'if'?

Comment: error: parse error on input ‘if’
   |
13 |         split' delim [] substr splittedStr     = splittedStr if substr == [] else reverse substr ++ splittedStr    | tried to put 'then' after reverse, but it's the same wrong

Comment: My main intent was go give you a basic idea on your solution. Since I get the feeling that you are not trying to learn but only trying to get your work done by other people's, I will stop helping you any further.  I suggest you use this answer as pseudo code and write your own function, or wait for another answer.

Answer (score 1):

So this is basically consists of 4 things.

1. Read Input from the stdin
2. Convert input string into list of strings
3. From the above list find out the strings which are palindromes
4. print these palindromes into file.

If you convert above into functions the signatures of these will be.

2. `String -> [String]`
3. `[String] -> [String]`

Don't bother about the signature of 1st and 4th for now. These are anyways one line code readily available on internet.

2 is a single function available in Data.List called `words`.

3 can be again in two parts. A function which find out if a given string is palindrome. Signature will be

`String -> Bool`

This is also one line code.

Once you have above function the only part remaining is filtering out the strings which are palindromes in given list of strings.

Comment: I didn't even knew about stdin, I thought it is in C++ only

Comment: @GeorgeBrussel stdin, stdout and stderr are standard terminology, when working with console.